# Best practice for saving Persistent Settings in C#

Tags: c#, persistence, application-settings

I have a C# WinForm that runs a batch file to flash a device through CMD.

I have a few variables (mostly file paths, but also a COM port # and a "setup" bool that drives a setup window if they're all unset) that are dependent on where the app was installed and what the port happens to be on that specific machine.

My initial thought process was to have a simple txt file that would have one of these on each line. I would stream read them in order at app startup and then decide to either run the app as normal, or first run a startup.

That said, there is a App.config already in my project, and I wondered if I would be better off using that, as I can't seem to include a txt file in my C# app the way I could in C++ and just refer to it.

Is one of these ways considered better than the other, or is it situational or just by choice? Or is there a better way I should be handling this that I haven't thought of?

I've never written a C# app to the point where I build it and set it up with an installer (there is a second program running in the background) so I'm a little lost with this - i'm not used to doing initial setup stuff as I do a lot of webapps which are all pretty persistent just by default or just write tools for myself and run them from within VB

Comment: I would look into using the registry to save these parameters.  The you can set them differently for each machine simply by update the registry.

Comment: Saw it and read it. He's on .NET 3.5 vs my 4.5, and he only really mentions 2 viable options (I, like him, won't be going anywhere near the registry if i can avoid it). No mention of using a txt file anywhere, which is why i asked if I should be doing it another way or if that just wasn't mentioned. Additionally (and, admittedly, I only hinted at this) I'm wondering if those file paths (in the config file) should be set at install or at initial runtime

Comment: Not that much has changed from .Net 3.5 to 4.5 where you cannot implement those suggestions.  Using a text file would work.  The only issue is it is not very secure.